# Node.js Mongoose addtoSet variable array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I have been having problem with updating the proper array in mongoose with new data using the addToSet method.

I want to add a new data into an array through mongoose. How ever in order to do that I have to put the proper index for the array I want to insert the array. This is the code

```
var arrayIndex ='This has been passed down from the function argument where this code is e.g. var arrayindex = 22'.

ModelName.findOneAndUpdate({ 
        _id:req.session.ss,
        }, 
        {$addToSet:{'first_array.0.second_array.'+arrayIndex+'.third_array':{
            field_name:value
        }
    }},
    {safe: true, upsert:true},
    function (err, updateDetail){
        if(err){
        }
        else{
             console.log(updateDetail)
        })
```

There is an error which is complaining about the + in the addToSet section. 
Please how can I put the value of the arrayIndex inside the addToSet value

This is my schema

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    main_section        :{
        first_name          : String
    },

    first_Array :[{//
        array_info          : String,
        second_array            :[{
            date_of_insertion   : Date,
            third_array         :[{//3rd level
                detail1             : String,//4th level
                field_name          : String
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

I would really appreciate any help. If I put $ operator it would insert into the first array and not the appropriate array where it is supposed to be.

Comment: I would give it a try

Comment: @JohnnyHK i am very grateful for pointing me out to the answer. it was what i was looking for.